# Updating an imported child theme from the wp-admin UI

Tags: child-theme

I have full access to the wp-admin area of a remote WordPress site.  I would prefer to work in this UI the whole time and not use FTP.

I have successfully imported my custom child theme for an existing parent theme, from within the wp-admin area.

My question - From the wp-admin area, can I simply re-upload the same child theme zip package every time I have new changes that needs to be applied to it?  Is this a suitable practice? Or will this cause issues?

Comment: I don't know about themes but that works fine for plugins, yes. (Although it can be disabled: on one site I work on I have to deactivate, delete, reupload and activate.)

Comment: thank you! I'll apply that strategy in my notes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading a new zip package should work the same way as updating themes or plugins.

Please not however that it will only add new files and overwrite existing ones. If you upload a new package without some files (eg. unnecessary CSS or JS), these files will remain on server. So, it is good to take a look from time to time and do some clean up if necessary.

Comment: That is exactly what I was curious about.  Many thanks!